# How come splitting return element in lists comprehension returns an empty bracket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), *"splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns []."*

```
>>> [i.split() for i in input()]
1 2
[['1'], [], ['2']]
```

However, interingly enough:

```
>>> [i for i in input().split()]
1 2
['1', '2']
```

Which leads us to deduce that **the None which creates the empty lists in the original example is not the result of splitting in of itself, or input(), but list comprehension.**

I read all [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) on lists comprehension and it revealed no answers.

Comment: It is not to do with the list comprehension. You are iterating and interacting with different objects.

Comment: To elaborate on what @AlexThornton said, its a string in the first case and a list in the second.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over a string; like calling `list()` on a string, iterating produces *individual characters*:

```
>>> list('1 2')
['1', ' ', '2']
>>> [c for c in '1 2']
['1', ' ', '2']
```

You are then applying `str.split()` to each individual character:

```
>>> '1'.split()
['1']
>>> ' '.split()
[]
>>> '2'.split()
['2']
```

The middle character is a space, so `str.split()` behaves **exactly** as advertised.

You don't need a list comprehension here at all. Just split the string returned by `input()`:

```
>>> input().split()
1 2
['1', '2']
```

All your second example does is loop over the list produced by that `str.split()` call and repeat the elements, one by one:

```
>>> [i for i in ['1', '2']]
['1', '2']
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not to do with the list comprehension. You are iterating over and interacting with different object types.

---

In the first example, you are iterating over a string, `'1 2'` so the elements are `['1', ' ', '2']`. Only *then* do you split them, returning the output specified. Looking at the documentation shown, we now know why the empty list is returned in the first example.

```
>>> [c for c in '1 2']
['1', ' ', '2']
```

---

However in the second example, you are iterating over `input().split()`, which is a list. This works normally because `'1 2'` is not an empty string. Therefore, `.split()` returns a list of elements, split in white-space by default.

```
>>> '1 2'.split()
>>> ['1', '2']
```